# Cross entropy function deriving

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-entropy

I was doing an exercise with these requirements:

Derive the gradient with regard to the inputs of a softmax function when cross entropy loss
is used for evaluation, i.e., find the gradients with respect to the softmax input vector θ, when the
prediction is made by $\hat{y} = softmax(θ)$. Remember the cross entropy function is ${dCE(y,\hat{y})}=-\sum_{i}y_{i}*log(\hat{y_{i}})$

And the solution is:

$\frac{dCE(y,\hat{y})}{d\hat{y}}=\hat{y}-y$

However, my calculations are these:

$\frac{dCE(y,\hat{y})}{d\hat{y}}=\frac{d(-\sum_{i}y_{i}*log(\hat{y_{i}}))}{d\hat{y}}$

$\frac{dCE(y,\hat{y})}{d\hat{y}}=-\sum_{i}y_{i}*\frac{1}{\hat{y_{i}}}*\hat{y_{i}}*(1-\hat{y_{i}})$

$\frac{dCE(y,\hat{y})}{d\hat{y}}=-\sum_{i}y_{i}*(1-\hat{y_{i}})$

$\frac{dCE(y,\hat{y})}{d\hat{y}}=\sum_{i}y_{i}*\hat{y_{i}} - \sum_{i}y_{i}$

$\frac{dCE(y,\hat{y})}{d\hat{y}}=\sum_{i}y_{i}*\hat{y_{i}} - y$

I don't know how to get from here to the solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From what you've described it seems like you're supposed to be using $\frac{d}{d\theta}$, not $\frac{d}{d\hat y}$. It also seems like you're making some mistakes in the derivative. As written, you should find $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \hat y_j} = -\frac{y_j}{\hat y_j}$.